# Send notification from Android app to any other device

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing an Android application that can send notifications (not "push") to any other Android device. Apart from `Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)` are there any alternatives to do so?

I do not plan to use `GCM`. My only requirement is to send the `notification` from my app to any other device via either Bluetooth or WiFi.

I have tried using the basic `Notification API` for Android but I could not send a notification to other device. It shows me a local notification.

Comment: The Notification API is for putting stuff on your phone, not for other devices.  Since you mention Bluetooth and Wifi-  will all devices be within a few feet of each other?  Or will they be farther apart?  If farther apart, you're pretty much forced to do it via a server.

Comment: no they will be close to each other. Is there a way to send a notification from within an app to another phone via bluetooth

Comment: Yes, but the devices would need to be paired, and the limit is 8 devices.  I would look into WifiDirect instead if there's more than 2 devices involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may helps https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-quickstart.html

firebase sync the devices and whatever you send it to server it automatically pushes that in other device

Comment: thank you :) recently i came to know about that . very usefull

Comment: how to use this to push notification. I am new to Firebase. can you provide some tutorial that does the same